# Ionic app gets stuck after splash screen for 0.005% of users

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I'm having an issue in my Ionic app. After the splash screen the user cannot tap on any buttons, and can't interact with the app at all. It's either stuck or simply non-responsive.

This happens consistently for those devices, therefore they are never able to sign up.

This is my `ionic info`:

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.3 (C:\Users\Simon K\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, browser 6.0.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic 5.4.4, cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 14 other plugins)
```

This is being reported by users on older devices. Most recently on a Samsung S5. I'm not sure if it's due to an older phone just freezing on our app, or perhaps it's some sort of network setting? Where it prevents Ionic from being responsive.

My config settings:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
```

If there is anything else I can provide that might be helpful, please let me know. I am at a loss as to how such a problem can be fixed as I have not been able to replicate the issue.

Is this potentially an Ionic issue?

Comment: try to inspect the app on chrome and show the console so we can help you

Comment: It's possibly a JS error, maybe a race condition since it happens on older (i.e. slower). You could try adding an error logger, e.g. [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com) or [Sentry](https://sentry.io/) (or create your own).

Answer (score 0):

Run app on the device on which you are getting this issue check logs using chrome://inspect